# basic wordpress plugin throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here is the basic wordpress plugin that hooks to woocommerce action tag. I try to understand the concept. But I get the error when I try to checkout on the page.

```
add_action( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wpwoopush_test');
function wpwoopush_test() {
    wp_mail($email,$title,$text);
    return true;
}
```

Error:

```
<div class="woocommerce-error">SyntaxError: Unexpected token &lt;</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
wp_mail() function is just an example $email,$title,$text defined correctly. It throws the same error event wp_mail() is commented out.

Comment: First, are you sure that `$titile` is spelt correctly? Second, is it possible that one of the strings `$email`, `$titile` or `$text` contain a `&lt;` character (which is `<`)?

Comment: that was just an example to show. the variables in wp_mail are well defined. I'm pretty sure that it's not the issue. Even I comment wp_mail function, it stll throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't even passing any variables to the function, so using wp_mail is useless because it has no information from the function to use.

You need to define the following:
`wp_mail($email,$titile,$text);`

More specifically:
`$email,$titile,$text`

inside your functions parameters: `function wpwoopush_test($email,$titile,$text)`

and as @Ben suggested, spell check on your variable names `($titile)` so you aren't using an undefined variable in the function if you go to edit it later.

Hope this helps!

Comment: wp_mail is not the problem. Even I comment it out it still throws the error.